# R:Error in UseMethod(generic = "as.sparse", object = x)

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFyBf.png)

I'm trying to use "Seurat" to analyze B cells for my tutor, but the following error occurs when I try to create the object and I don't know how to correct it.

```
pbmc <- CreateSeuratObject( counts = BC.data$'B Cells`, Project = " BC.data",min.cells = 3, min.features = 200)
```

> Error in UseMethod(generic = "as.sparse", object = x) :
> no applicable method for 'as.sparse' applied to an object of class "Seurat"

Comment: Your column name in `counts=BC.data$ etc` should be between backtics but the first is a single quote.

Comment: I'm very sorry , because I'm a beginner, I can't fully understand your answer, can you explain in more detail, thank you very much.

Comment: In  ```BC.data$'B Cells` ```, change the single quote to backtick.

Comment: Your answer perfectly solved my problem. Sorry because I'm new to Stack Overflow and haven't figured out how to accept your answer.

Comment: Glad it helped. My answer is a comment, not an answer. I have posted as a comment because the problem is caused by a typo, it's not a coding problem. There's no need to accept it.